# Strapi giving me DB errors in production, even though I'm using correct credentials

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, environment-variables, strapi

EDIT: I found a file at /config/database.js which is used to connect to sqlite in development. When I change the client name from sqlite to postgres, that's when the trouble starts.

Isn't strapi supposed to ignore files like this in production? How can I get strapi to ignore this file, and just use my postgres db?

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'sqlite',
        filename: env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db'),
      },
      options: {
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

End edit.

I'm trying to get my strapi app to start up in production, but it keeps erroring out saying

```
[2020-07-22T01:15:40.246Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2020-07-22T01:15:40.247Z] error error: password authentication failed for user "<redacted>"
```

The rest of the output is related to pg, which leads me to think that this is a DB connection error.
I can log into my db from the command line using `psql -U postgres -W`, which confirms that I know my password.

In addition, I'm using pm2 to run things, and instead of using process.env in that file, I just added the db variables directly, but that made no difference.

The application has been built in production mode. I have 3 dbs in pg, one called postgres, one with my apps name, and another called strapi.

Thanks

my /config/enviroronments/production.database.json looks like this

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "bookshelf",
      "settings": {
        "client": "postgres",
        "host": "${process.env.DATABASE_HOST || '127.0.0.1'}",
        "port": "${process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 27017}",
        "database": "${process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'strapi'}",
        "username": "${process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME || ''}",
        "password": "${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || ''}"
      },
      "options": {
        "ssl": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I have a .env file at the root of the backend app that looks like this

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME="<redacted - all letters>"
DATABASE_USERNAME="<redacted - all letters>"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="<redacted - all letters>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. When I created the app, I used sqlite as my db. As a result, the default database.js file wasn't set up in a way that could be overwritten with env variables.

I created a new local Strapi app with pgsql as my db, and copied the contents of the database.js file to my server. All working now.

New file for reference

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'postgres',
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'my-strapi-project'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'testing'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'testing'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
      },
      options: {}
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation in development. I created a strapi app with SQLite and decided to use PostgreSQL. That's where the trouble came in. So the fix was as follows:

app_name/config/database.js

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
      port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'db_name'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
      ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
    },
  },
});
```

Your dependencies under app_name/package.json should be like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.1.8",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.1.8",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.1.8",
    "pg": "8.6.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[2023-02-19 11:27:27.197] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-02-19 11:27:27.199] error: password authentication failed for user "root"

FIX==>

```
su - postgres

psql postgres

CREATE ROLE root SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

The point of interest here is the module used with strapi .

configuration file database.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
   defaultConnection: "default",
   connection: {
     client: "postgres",
     connection: {
       host: "127.0.0.1",
       port: 5432,
       database: "dbname",
       username: "postgres",
       password: "password",
       ssl: false
     },
     debug: true,
     useNullAsDefault: true
   }
});
```

version package.json

```
  "@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^2.0.3",
     "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.6.1,",
     "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.6.1,",
     "@strapi/strapi": "4.6.1,",
     "better-sqlite3": "8.0.1",
     "pg": "8.6.0"
```

check version

```
/etc/postgresql/{{version-postsql}}/main/pg_hba.conf


local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

restart  postgresql

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service

su - postgres

psql

DROP root;

CREATE ROLE root WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWOR 'password......';

CREATEDB dbname;
```

I don't know why it took the initial role of root but the above simple solution worked for me